# Getting comments from Facebook photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a project and I need to retrieve all of the photos a user is tagged in, that's not a problem. I also need to get a list of all comments for each photo, which has proved to be somewhat annoying. Here is what I think should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>HipWall</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        {% for photo in stream["data"] %}                                                                                                                                           

            {{ photo["comments"] }}<br /><br />

        {% end %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Where stream holds the response from calling https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

Aside from "comments", everything else seems to work. "pictures", "source" and "tags" all return what they should.

When I start up my server though I get a 500: Internal Server Error response and my logs tell me that photo["comments"] is a key error.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your question is a bit vague. What template engine do you use, how do you put together the data?

But, to answer your question: The photo stream does not include comments innately. There is only a **connection** to photos available. Have a look at the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150146071831729/comments). You need to get the comments for each photo with `graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/comments`.